# Why is the same .class file of a different size?

Tags: java, javac

I noticed a difference in file sizes between the `.class` files given to me (compiled with Ant `javac` on a build server) and with Maven (locally). I've looked at the contents of the class files and see differences, and I'd be interested to understand the origin of these differences.

#### Decompiled

Given to me:

```
public class TableData
{
  public static String[] getTableNames()
  {
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList(TableData.Table.values().length);
    for (TableData.Table localTable : TableData.Table.values()) {
      localArrayList.add(localTable.getName());
    }
    return (String[])localArrayList.toArray(new String[localArrayList.size()]);
  }
```

Local build:

```
public class TableData
{
  public static String[] getTableNames()
  {
    List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList(TableData.Table.values().length);
    for (TableData.Table table : TableData.Table.values()) {
      tableNames.add(table.getName());
    }
    return (String[])tableNames.toArray(new String[tableNames.size()]);
  }
```

#### File Size

Given to me: 1371 bytes

Local build: 1819 bytes

#### Using `javap`

A lot of similarities, such as:

```
InnerClasses:
   public static final #17= #16 of #14; //Table=class (et cetera)
minor version: 0
major version: 51
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
```

Given to me:

```
#23 = Utf8               Code
#24 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
#25 = Utf8               getTableNames
#26 = Utf8               ()[Ljava/lang/String;
```

Local build:

```
#23 = Utf8               Code
#24 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
#25 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
#26 = Utf8               this
#27 = Utf8               L.../TableData;
#28 = Utf8               getTableNames
#29 = Utf8               ()[Ljava/lang/String;
```

#### Compiler Invocation

Given to me:

```
<javac target="1.7"  source="1.7" srcdir="${src.dir}"
    excludes="..." destdir="..." classpathref="app.classpath"
    verbose="${compile.verbose}" debug="${compile.debug}"
    debuglevel="${compile.debuglevel}"  includeAntRuntime="true" />


compile.debug: on
compile.debugLevel: lines,source
```

Local build:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The question: **why?**

Comment: what are the flag differenec passed in in both execution ?

Comment: It seems that your local build contains more debug symbol information.

Comment: NB the cast in the `return` statement is redundant.

Comment: @EJP Please mind that you are looking at decompiled code. Whatever is redundant is put in there by the decompiler.

Comment: Thank you all. I added information about the compiler invocation to the original question.

Comment: @EJP It's decompiled code, meaning the generic information is gone. The cast isn't redundant at all in that scenario; it's essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the Maven compiler plugin:

> `debug`
>   `boolean`
>   Set to true to include debugging information in the compiled class files.
>   **Default value is**: true.

Changing this configuration property removes the difference in file sizes:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <debug>false</debug>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```